# css, html, angularjs or jade issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am having issue getting my css to display. I think its because I applied the html through a directive.

here is my js file:

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.user = {
    name:'Chelsey',
    address:{
        street:'PO Box 123',
        city: 'Secret Rebel Base',
        planet: 'Yavin 4'
    },
    friends:[
        'Hans',
        'chewbacca',
        'Leia'
    ]
}

});

angular.module('app').directive('userInfoCard', function(){
return {
   templateUrl:"userInfoCard.html",
   restrict:"E",
   controller: function($scope){
       $scope.knightMe=function(user){
           user.rank="knight";
       };
   }
}
});
```

my root html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
   <scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js">      </script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.jade" type="text/css/">
    <script src= "app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller = "mainCtrl" class="container" style ="padding-top:30px">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    **<user-info-card></user-info-card>**
    </body>
    </html>
```

The html that I want the css applied too (user-info-card.html):

```
<div class="panel panel-Primary">
    **<div class="panel-heading">{{user.name}}</div>**
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-show = 'user.address'>
            <h4>Address: </h4>
            {{user.address.street}}<br />
            {{user.address.city}}<br />
            {{user.address.planet}}
        </div><br />
        <h4> Friends:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='friend in user.friends'>
                 {{friend}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-show ="user.rank">
            Rank: {{user.rank}}
        </div>
        <button ng-show="!user.rank" class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="knightMe(user)">Knight Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css in jade:

```
style.
    .panel-heading {
       text-decoration-color: blue;
    }
```

I am just trying to get my css to display {{user.name}} in blue right now but it keeps saying that the class is never used. I am a little new to this so anything would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know what is "jade", but why it's `style.
    .panel-heading` not just `.panel-heading`?

Comment: jade can be used to write html and css. From what I have seen the 'style.' designates the following code as css. So this should be fine.

Comment: The `style` in a jade template would designate the `<style>` element in an html template. So it would be useful for css rules defined in your html. Here, you linked a css stylesheet, so `style.` shouldn't be here. Also, the html you posted is not a jade template, it is just html.

Comment: Ah ok thanks that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-decoration-color` is for the color of the underline. You might want to use `color` instead.

Also, please note that `text-decoration-color` has, as of now, poor browser support. See [browser support on caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration)

EDIT: Jade is a templating engine for html documents, not for css stylesheets. So in your root html, include the stylesheet as the following :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`

and in **style.css** :

```
.panel-heading {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: yeah I tried that, did't work it keeps telling me that the class .panel-heading is not being used but it is in my user-info-card so I don't know why its not displaying the css.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'? Do you see the `<div class="panel-heading">` in the rendered view?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by render view... the code editor I am using keeps telling me that the class "panel-heading" is never used. I've tried multiple things in the class to give me some indication that it is working but  the css really just doesn't get referenced at all and I can't figure out why.

Comment: By rendered view I mean the output in the browser. Under `Hello World` do you see the user name, i.e. Chelsey in your example?

Comment: yes everything in the html displays, its the css that is not getting looked at.

Comment: Ok, so it seems your `.panel-heading` css rule has not been parsed. By the way I noticed you wrote `type="text/css/"` instead of `type="text/css">` in your `index.html` file

Comment: I've completed the answer, as it seems you are misusing jade